# Flask app.route always giving 404 errors except /

Tags: python, flask, routes

I have a Flask app that kept giving 404 error on any route other than `/`

```
 33     @app.route("/")
 34     def hello_world():
 35         return "Hello, Faiss Flask!"
 36
 37     @app.route("/echo", methods=["POST"])
 38     def echo():
 39         return flask.jsonify(request.data)
 40
```

Then I use `Postman` to try on the service.
In the console log I got:

```
faissflask_1  | INFO:werkzeug:172.19.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2022 06:19:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 
faissflask_1  | INFO:werkzeug:172.19.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2022 06:21:52] "POST /echo HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: could you add the request you send via postman? Also including the Post Body you send?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, thanks for the follow up. I think I got the root cause. After I adding new API, `docker-compose` doesn't automatically build new image. It only attach the latest image I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out the root cause.
I was running it with `docker-compose up` which only attaching the existing images rather than build on any updates to the service code.

Comment: ok yes you could add the option `--build` to rebuild the containers